# Any legal/Microsoft way to make Windows 7 installation legal by purchasing a key for it

Tags: windows-7, license-key, licensing

I searched a lot and there are resources which point to e-bay and others but all that is third party.

I would like to buy JUST THE KEY for Windows 7 NOT the media, so I can make the already working copy of Windows 7 legal/activated.

Reason for this is to save some money. I have the media just give me the key, and only charge me for the key.

Comment: The cost of the media is a negligible proportion of the cost of the licence. I don't think you'll save that much money.

Comment: Yeah, the plastic itself costs like 10 cents.  The reason why Microsoft charges you for media is because of shipping and handling.

Comment: You can download a 100% legal copy of Windows 7 that is free that is distrubuted by Microsoft's partner.  There is a question on this very site with a link.  So your desire not to purchase the media isn't going to save you any money.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Buy the Download version:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/buy/default.aspx

You should receive a key without having to actually download (although keeping a copy of the ISO will always be handy!)

Comment: Ha! Even then, a normal system builder version is cheaper

Comment: if by system builder version you mean OEM then that would be breaking the licence terms

Comment: no, I don't mean the OEM versions. With XP you could get the cheaper versions which were only the license stickers, booklet and CD. Weren't breaking any licensing terms here!

Comment: As I understand it, the sticker is for the OEM version! The sticker is to be affixed to the computer once built. These versions are only licenced if purchased with hardware. (I may be wrong!)

Comment: I think they tried to make it like this. But EU law forbid this kind of association. They even made selling the stickers only possible in the EU (the laws). So we in the EU are free to do as we wish with the stickers. They can't be permanently associated with a pc system as far as I know. So I should have mentioned I live in the EU!

Comment: Me too, so that is great news :)

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a upgrade key at any Best Buy, but for a new copy of the same version you need to get the media per Microsoft:

> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Get-a-new-Windows-7-product-key